# Active X error 429 cannot create an object , when I try to run the below macro

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint, activexobject

So, I am trying to create a macro which will copy data from an excel sheet (in this case sheet "Regions") and then copy paste in an existing powerpoint template, slide no 4.

Please note the powerpoint and excel file both are saved in a dropbox folder. (if that changes anything)
I am not an expert in VBA so cannot understand why it is showing me this error.

The code is below:

```
Sub excelrangetopowerpoint()

Dim rng As Range
Dim powerpointapp As Object
Dim mypresentation As Object
Dim destinationPPT As String
Dim myshape As Object
Dim myslide As Object

Set rng = Worksheets("regions").Range("B1:N18")

On Error Resume Next

Set powerpointapp = CreateObject("powerpoint.application")
detinationppt = ("C:\Users\OLX-Admin\Dropbox (Corporate Finance)\Naspers Monthly Reporting\Prep for call\From teams\FY2019\OLX Group Monthly Report_Sep'18_Macro.pptx")
PowerPoint.Presentations.Open (destinationPPT)

On Error GoTo 0

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set mypresentation = PowerPoint.ActivePresentation
Set myslide = mypresentation.Slides(4)

rng.Copy

myslide.Shapes.PasteSpecial DataType:=2 '2 = enhanced metafile
Set myshape = myslide.Shapes(myslide.Shapes.Count)

myshape.Left = 152
myshape.Top = 152

powerpointapp.Visible = True
powerpointapp.Activate

Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: You have a typo where you assign the Powerpoint filename (`detinationppt` instead of `destinationppt`). Always use **Option Explicit** to avoid such errors.

Comment: thanks, but I still get the same error. "activeX cant create the object". Should I change my code?

Comment: I have a code which is working fine,  it is copying a data range from excel and pasting it into new powerpoint file.
I want help to change it to copy paste into an existing powerpoint file, rather than creating a new one.

I want this range to be pasted in an existing ppt slide no 4.

Comment: Here is the code: (if this helps), this is working fine but this creates a new excel sheet and I want to create into an existing. Please see the answer below:

Answer (score 0):

You have two undefined variables in your code

`detinationppt` instead of `destinationppt`
You assign the PowerPoint Application Object to `powerpointapp`, but 2 lines later you access an (undefined) object `PowerPoint`

You can easily avoid such errors by putting `Option Explicit` at the top of your code.

Next thing is that you can assign the opened presentation rather than access the `ActivePresentation`. I made a test, and for me accessing  `ActivePresentation` failed.

And please don't put `On Error resume Next` into your code unless you know exactly what you're doing. If you want to avoid a runtime error because Powerpoint coudn't be started, you have to handle the error case by yourself (as it is done by your "code which is working fine"). For the beginning, simply remove it.

This code worked for me (of course with a different file name)

```
Set powerpointApp = CreateObject("powerpoint.application")
destinationPPT = C:\Users\OLX-Admin\Dropbox (Corporate Finance)\Naspers Monthly Reporting\Prep for call\From teams\FY2019\OLX Group Monthly Report_Sep'18_Macro.pptx    
Set myPresentation = powerpointApp.Presentations.Open(destinationPPT)
Set mySlide = myPresentation.Slides(4)
(...)
```

Answer (score 0):

First, add this line to the top of your module, as the very first text in the whole thing:

```
Option Explicit
```

Then, in the Menu bar click "Debug" and "Compile VBA Project"

You will get a series of Error Messages, like this:

> Compile error:
>
> Variable not defined

And the variable that has not been defined will be Selected for you by VBA.  Most of these seem to be typos, such as

- `detinationppt = ("C:` instead of `destinationPPT = ("C:`
- `PowerPoint.Presentations.Open (destinationPPT)` instead of `PowerPointApp.Presentations.Open (destinationPPT)`
- `Set mypresentation = PowerPoint.ActivePresentation` instead of `Set mypresentation = PowerPointApp.ActivePresentation`

Basically, it looks like you have copied and pasted 2 different blocks of code together, and forgotten to check that the Variable Names all match up (also, one seems to be [Early Binding, and the other is Late Binding](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/245115/using-early-binding-and-late-binding-in-automation))

If you go to "Tools" > "Options..." > "Editor", there is a Tickbox, "Require Variable Declaration".  Turn this on, leave this on, and use the "Compile VBA Project" option regularly to check for typos and similar errors.

Answer (score -1):

Here is the code which is working fine:

```
Sub ExcelRangeToPowerPoint()

Dim rng As Range
Dim PowerPointApp As Object
Dim myPresentation As Object
Dim mySlide As Object
Dim myShape As Object

'Range to copy
Set rng = Worksheets("regions").Range("B1:N18")

On Error Resume Next

Set PowerPointApp = GetObject(class:="PowerPoint.Application")

Err.Clear

'If PowerPoint is not already open then open PowerPoint
If PowerPointApp Is Nothing Then Set PowerPointApp = CreateObject(class:="PowerPoint.Application")

'Handle if the PowerPoint Application is not found
If Err.Number = 429 Then
MsgBox "PowerPoint could not be found, aborting."
Exit Sub
End If

On Error GoTo 0

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'To create new presentation
Set myPresentation = PowerPointApp.Presentations.Add
'to add new slide to the Presentation
Set mySlide = myPresentation.Slides.Add(1, 11) '11 = ppLayoutTitleOnly

rng.Copy

'Paste to PowerPoint and position
mySlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial DataType:=2  '2 = ppPasteEnhancedMetafile
Set myShape = mySlide.Shapes(mySlide.Shapes.Count)

myShape.Left = 152
myShape.Top = 152

PowerPointApp.Visible = True
PowerPointApp.Activate

Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```

Comment: Please don't put a change in your question as answer - instead, edit your original question